# Upserting a custom bridging object

Tags: error-messages, upsert

I have been trying to upsert using the Bulk Data wizard and keep running into the same error no matter what I try. (And I have done this before with no problems - same object and type of data.)

I choose Custom objects and then my object which is "Course Participations."

**Match by:** Name

**Which Contact field in your file specifies the Master/Detail relationship?:** Contact Name (choices are SF ID, external ID, none)

**Which Course field in your file do you want to match against to set the Course Title lookup field?:** Course Name/SF ID (I have chosen both.)

I map the fields and use the SF ID for the Course name because it needs to be unique. No  matter what combination of choices I make, I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Any advice greatly appreciated!!

This is the error:
**DUPLICATE_VALUE:Duplicate external id specified: a01o000000GXQar:Name --

(That number is the SF ID for the Course Name)**

**This the object:**

Custom Object Definition Detail
Course Participation
Course Participations
Object Name CourseContactAssociation
API Name    CourseContactAssociation__c 
Allow Sharing   Checked
Allow Bulk API Access   Checked
Allow Streaming API Access  Checked
Track Field History Not Checked
Deployment Status    Deployed
Allow Search    Checked

**Standard Fields**
Course Participation    Name    Auto Number

**Custom Fields & Relationships Help Custom Fields & Relationships** Help (New Window)
Action
Field Label

Course Title
Course_Title__c Lookup(Course)
Participant
Participant__c  Master-Detail(Contact)
Role
Role__c Picklist (Multi-Select)
Term
    Term_del__c Text(6)
Year/Level
Year_Level__c   Picklist

Comment: So basically, Salesforce is finding multiple records with the same external ID (Course Name Id in your case) and therefore raises the error. So the ID you selected is not unique. See this. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm How many records are you loading?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am trying to add students (participants) to that course (the SF ID) with Term, role, and level information. So "Course Participation" links a specific course (a custom object) to a contact. I have done it a million times before using the same template. And this is only 11 contacts as I was testing it. : /

Comment: There is no M-D relationship with Contact. That should be set to None. For the Course field, only choose the SF ID, not both. Run a SOQL query or do a dupe check to make certain you don't have multiple records for your Course if the error message persists.

Comment: Ugh - still did not work. And I have no experience with SOQL queries.  From the reading I have done, I cam up with this query :Select(Id) FROM Course_Offering__c WHERE Name = 'D-Lab: Design'); but then I get this error: required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Select'  I am so frustrated because like I said, I have upserted these before using the exact same template. And I have double checked the COurse listings and the ID is correct.